# Silverlight: Can I load ViewModel in advance during Mef Init?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, prism, mef

I am using **MEF** and **PRISM** in my silverlight app. I want to load all the shared ViewModels in the MefInit so that **EventAggregator** works well.

The problem is I have a publisher in one ViewModel (shared) and the subscriber in another. The first ViewModel gets imported when the corresponding View is loaded. Now on some event I want to navigate to a different View that has a different ViewModel (shared), for which I am using EventAggregator.

But when I publish from the former ViewModel, as the latter ViewModel is still not loaded and has not yet subscribed to the event so it fails. But as the VMs are shared, eventing works after the first call.

Please suggest, what shall I do and where am I doing wrong.

Comment: IMHO: There is still a need for controller classes in PRISM (MVCVM?) :). Those lightweight classes can all be loaded at startup and handle all eventing independent of any data or VM class. VMs should not be making decisions (sending/receiving events). VMs are just a binding layer for the View. If you add controller classes you would not have the problem you described.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please direct me to some article where I can understand what you actually mean?

Comment: It's MVC applied to MVVM. PRISM modules register *only* controllers, which when initialised subscribe to and publish messages, register the views and VMs they are responsible for. It was a pattern we saw in a commercial Silverlight code-generating/modelling package and we use it on all projects now. This way Views and VMS can be load on demand in MEF, but the logic (which is usually a small amount of code) is present early on in the controllers. As you found you can't subscribe to events after they are published. (I prefer standard PRISM to MEF, but most principles apply to both).